# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, list, int, typeerror

I'm trying to create a program in python that will tell you the day of the week you were born using the Zeller algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence but it's giving me this error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'

Why is that?

```
date = raw_input ("Introduce here the day, month and year you were born like this: DDMMYYYY")

if date.isdigit() and len(date) == 8:
    day = date[0:2]
    month = date[2:4]
    year = date[4:8]
    day = int(day)
    month = int(month)
    year = int(year)
    result = (day + (month + 1) * 2.6, + year % 100 + (year % 100) / 4 - 2 * [year / 100]) % 7
```

(It's the first program I create by myself, so be nice please ;) )

Comment: `[year / 100]` change this to : `(year / 100)`, also in `(day + (month + 1) * 2.6` where's the closing parenthesis? (remove the `,`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening in answer to your direct question has been answered by @mellamokb and comments...

However, I would point out that Python already this builtin and would make it easier:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.strptime('1312981', '%d%m%Y')
# datetime(1981, 12, 13, 0, 0)
```

Then you can perform calculations more easily on an object that is actually a `datetime` rather than co-erced strings...

Answer (score 3):

I think `2 * [year / 100]` should be parentheses instead of brackets, otherwise it indicates you want to make a single-element list:

```
(year % 100) / 4 - 2 * (year / 100))
                       ^          ^ change [] to ()
```

Comment: plus the `,` after `2.6` is also an Error.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I did this and the comma thing and it's working!