# List comprehension and powers

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a list from 1 to 21 and to power them to the 3d. In school i could do it, but i downloaded a way newer version and now i get the following error:
 for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
This is my code:

```
A=[range(21)]
print A
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]
In [14]:

A2=[x**3 for x in A]
print A2
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 [x**3 for x in A]
      2 print A2

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
```

I am using ipython JUPYTER

Comment: `A` contains another list and not numbers. Try create `A=range(21)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042291/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-list)

Answer (score 2):

The first line should be:

```
A=range(21)
```

(that is, remove the square brackets `[]`.

The way you have it, you've made a "list of lists".  You want a list of numbers, and range() returns that.

Answer (score 0):

When you set

```
A = [range(21)]
```

you set the first element of list A as a list (your printed value of A is a list inside a list). To prevent that, use

```
A = range(21)
```

The rest of your code is fine.